# Slow on browsing web, but normal when using apt-get

Tags: networking

I have a problem with my fresh instalation of Ubuntu 11.10. The problem happen when i start up my browser and accessing website such google, askubuntu.com, facebook and other sites. frustate on the situation i try watch the progress in system monitor. the result from monitor shows that there is no data transfer when i try to accessing the page. firstly, i assume that it is the trouble from my ISP or my home connection. But it is not. When i try pinging google it shows transaction between my computer and the network but still null from browser. Then i tried to test the aptitude and it was work fine but still the browser won't recieve any packet from the internet.

Here is the detail of my tools :

1. Laptop : Toshiba Satellite e205 (network card atheros)
2. Operating System : Ubuntu 11.04 dual booted with Win7
3. Browser : Mozilla Firefox comes up with the Ubuntu 11.10 installation
4. Chrome  : Last version (just yesterday install it)

Thank You before :)

[this question posted via win]

Comment: please name which browser u r using

Comment: Yes, It would help to know what browser you are using, and maybe what plugins it has, a plugin may cause this or anything like that,

Comment: Have you tried different browsers? Does `wget` a page work? Do you have a slow connection or not connection at all from your browser?

Comment: i'am using default browser in ubuntu. Mozilla Firefox. i had also try the up to dated chrome from google yesterday. i though it may come up with the Atheros brand. hmm... i might make some screencast to make sure of it.

Comment: 1. Try connecting using an ethernet cable. Does it work? 2. We need more information: a) Router brand & model number b) Output of commands `lspci -nn` and `lsusb` (edit your question and add them) 3. Are you using a proxy or a firewall? 4. Were you downloading any torrents lately? 5. Search for program "Additional drivers" in unity. See if you have any recommended drivers to install.

Comment: Also output of `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for program "network connections" in unity (or run `nm-connection-editor` in terminal). Select your connection and click edit.

1. Set MTU instead of automatic to be something less than 1500 (e.g. try: 1460, 1470, 1480, 1490).
   Note: You can reset it back to automatic if you set it as 0.
2. Set IPv6 Method to "Ignored".

Click Save.

Then restart your router and restart your computer for settings to take effect. (Or disconnect/reconnect to your connection from the indicator tray icon)

If none of the MTU values help, see the 2 comments I wrote above.

Comment: thanks for the answer. it is very helpful. but anyway, how'd you find  the solution like that? so in the future i may figure it out before further asking to the forum. gracias.. :)

Comment: I had the same problem with a router I bought (TP-Link w8960n). I bet it's the MTU that was the problem. I don't know much about MTU size, but I know that it is a packet size, the bigger it is, the more chances you have to have problems with "some" websites. The transfer of packets can sometimes choke a modem (especially the ones with enabled Firewall and SPI Firewall), so using MTU from 1440 up to 1480 is recommended. All you need to do is test which one is better for your connection.

Comment: The saying "not all heros wear caps" applies to you, sir!